# Query on <url-pattern> in <filter-mapping>

Tags: servlet-filters

Need to invoke a Filter based on Filter Mapping. Stanza is web.xml looks like

```
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FeatureFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/xyz?UUId=urn:abc:asf/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/mac/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>       
  </filter-mapping>
```

The request URL is ip:port/contextroot/xyz?UUId=urn:abc:asf

Pattern /mac/* works fine however /xyz?UUId=urn:abc:asf/* is not allowing to trigger FeatureFilter.  How to handle Query parameters in URL pattern.